# How to create a dualboot disk image to install on multiple laptops?

Tags: multi-boot, disk-image

I'd like to setup multiple laptops in the same way: dualboot Windows and Linux. I understand the easiest would be to create a disk image with both operating systems and then write this image to all laptops. Assuming the disks of the laptops may have different capacities, is this possible and if not, what would be a sensible way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Variant A:
Create your image on the smallest possible disk size, then use the OS facilities to expand the partitions to the desired size. Windows and Linux can both increase the size of a mounted partition and file system.

Variant B:
Use clonezilla or a similar distro to transfer the partitions one by one, increasing their size in the process